# Jquery tablesorter: Select for external filter instead of input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Hi I am trying to add add select tag outside the table and make it filter a specific column in the table.

Several others have asked about this, but all the 'working' examples I have found are actually not working:

Here is an example:

- [Question asked at Git hub](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/671)
- [Then none working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/LR3sX/61/)

  ```
  <select id="select1" data-column="1">
      <option value="">First Name</option>
  </select>

  var arry = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptionSource($t[0], 1);

  $('#select1').append('<option>' + arry.join('</option><option>') + '</option>');
  ```

Has something changed with the plugin?

All guidance are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was a bug in the last update which has been fixed and is currently only available within the working branch ([patch](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/commit/d55a99eb4c2a87a017bda37bd51c81e32968dbdf)).

```
// line 1143 - 1144 of jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js
ffxn = wo.filter_columnFilters ? 
    c.$filters.add(c.$externalFilters).filter('[data-column="'+ columnIndex + '"]').find('select option:selected').attr('data-function-name') || '' : '';
```

Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/LR3sX/84/) using the working branch code.

I'll push an update today to get this fix into the master. Sorry about that.

---

Master branch updated. The demo from your question is working now.

Comment: Thanks Mottie. Works great now.